# Derivative of a logarithmic function with $\frac{C}{x}$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

The function is

$$G(x)=4^{\frac{C}{x}}$$
I have $u=\frac{C}{x}$, then I calculate $$\frac{d}{du}4^u=u(4)^{u-1}$$
But does  $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{C}{x}=C$$ 
because I don't know if $C$ is a constant or a independent variable.

Comment: $\frac{d}{du}4^u=4^u\ln4\ne u(4)^{u-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

if $f(x) = a^x$ you can write

$$
f(x) = e^{\ln a^x} = e^{x \ln a}
$$

So the derivative is

$$
\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x} = (\ln a )e^{x\ln a} = a^x \ln a
$$

Comment: Could you use the terms that are in my question cause I'm confused about what I'm reading.

Comment: @EricBrown 

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} 4^{C/x} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}e^{C\ln 4/x} = ...
$$